# Using cin to input array values

Tags: c++, arrays, cin

I am trying to take a variable use it for a size declarator into an array.  I am having trouble getting the data into the array.  What will happen then is that I will divide the array into an average and return a char value.  The only problem I have is with inputting data into the array.  Thanks in advance here is the code.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int average(int&);

char grade(int);

int main()
{
    int array = {};
    int numgrades;
    int total = 0;

    cout << "Enter the number of grades" << endl;
    cin >> numgrades;

    for (int i = 0; i < numgrades; i++) {
        cout << "Enter a numeric grade between 0 - 100" << endl;
        cin >> i;
        total += i;

    }

    int average = total / numgrades;


    char result = grade(average);


    cout << "The grade is " << result << "." << endl;

    return 0;
}

char grade(int avg)
{
    if (avg >= 90) {
        return 'A';
    }
    else if (avg >= 80 && avg < 90) {
        return 'B';
    }
    else if (avg >= 70 && avg < 80) {
        return 'C';
    }
    else if (avg >= 60 && avg < 70) {
        return 'D';
    }
    else
    {
        return 'F';
    }

}
```

Comment: You don't have an array... Consider reviewing how to declare and use an array. Also, think about what the variable `i` is and what  `cin >> i;` does.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have some critical problems in your code, this is what will do the work:

```
cin >> numgrades;

int *array = new int[numgrades] ;

for (int i = 0; i < numgrades; i++) {
    cout << "Enter a numeric grade between 0 - 100" << endl;
    cin >> array[i];
    total += array[i];

}
```

The important parts are creating the array **dynamically**, using the `new` statement and passing the wished size. Also your problem was in overriding `i` by the `cin >> i` line, instead you need to save the value to the array at `i`, like this `cin >> array[i]`.

For more ways work with dynamic data and arrays in C++ I recommend you read about [std::vector](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/).